# help in finding error using \newenvironment

Tags: environments

I am learning `\newenvironment` and I need help in finding where my error is in making `\newenvironment`. I get a Latex error and I do not see what I am doing wrong.  I am trying to reduce code duplication by making new environment. I will show the code before, and then the code when I try to make an environment.

Here is before, which works with no error:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{240,240,240}
\usepackage{upquote} %to fix string quotes    
\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{colback=bg,size=minimal,hbox,listing only,
                     listing options={style=Matlab-editor,
                                      basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize,
                                      breaklines         = false,
                                      escapechar         = `
                                      }%
                      }%
K=[3 -2;-2 2]; M=[1 0;0 3];
[phi,lam]=eig(K,M)
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

Compiled with lualatex and it gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is the new code, which tries to make `\newenvironment` called `matlab` with same exact definition as above.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{240,240,240}    
\usepackage{upquote} %to fix string quotes

\newenvironment{matlab}
{
  \begin{tcblisting}{colback=bg,size=minimal,hbox,listing only,
                     listing options={style=Matlab-editor,
                                      basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize,
                                      breaklines         = false,
                                      escapechar         = `
                                      }%
                      }%
}%
{
 \end{tcblisting}\ignorespacesafterend
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{matlab}
K=[3 -2;-2 2]; M=[1 0;0 3];
[phi,lam]=eig(K,M)
\end{matlab}
\end{document}
```

When I compile the above, I get

```
lualatex foo2.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0.1 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5863) 
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(./foo2.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
...
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)))
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text> 
\par 
<*> foo2.tex

?
```

I looked up the definition of `\newenvironment` and I do not see what mistake I am doing. Definition

```
    \newenvironment{nam}[args]{begdef}{enddef}
```

Using TL 2015

Comment: Isn't that just another verbatim environment? Like `lstlisting`, `align` and others?

Comment: @Johannes_B I do not know. Is there a limitation in making newenvironments? I keep forgetting if there is. So many rules to keep track of when programming Latex. Is there a way to go around it then so I do not have to duplicate same code each time?

Comment: It is the very same limitation as with `align` and `lstlisting`. The rule is pretty simple: Some environments are impossible to create.

Comment: And to be honest, i pretty much think that LaTeX is the wrong input tool for you. People are doing some great stuff based on xml to create different output formats.

Comment: but how to do math in XML?  Any way, I simply wanted to make a "function" like, which I understand is what newenvironment is supposed to be, so that I can "call" it each time, instead of repeating the same boiler plate code each time.

Comment: Have a look at https://tug.org/pracjourn/2005-2/flynn/flynn.pdf

Comment: I think reading the `tcolorbox` manual about `\newtcblisting` could be useful.

Comment: @Johannes_B I am still confused about the rule. You say `It is the very same limitation as with align and lstlisting. The rule is pretty simple`. Now I am trying to make new environment, where in tex4ht mode, I want to enject some HTML code. WHich is allowed in tex4ht mode. But Latex is not happy. So I have no idea if this falls into the no-no rule, or it is something else. This is all so confusing.

Comment: The rule was ` Some environments are impossible to create.` and should be altered to end with `with newcommand.` As i said before, since you are looking for different outputs, i wouldn't use LaTeX. Though it *is* possible to have it, your documents are so freaking complex, that the simple tools fail. If you try out a XML workflow, i would be interested in the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `\begin{tcblisting}` inside the argument to another command, just like `\begin{verbatim}` or `\begin{lstlisting}`.

The `listings` package has `\lstnewenvironment` for coping with the case of defining new environments based on `lstlisting` and, of course, also the `tcolorbox` package has the appropriate feature, called `\newtcblisting` (see page 290 in the manual, section 15.2).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{240,240,240}    
\usepackage{upquote} %to fix string quotes

\newtcblisting{matlab}{
  colback=bg,
  size=minimal,
  hbox,
  listing only,
  listing options={
    style=Matlab-editor,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize,
    breaklines= false,
    escapechar=`,
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{matlab}
K=[3 -2;-2 2]; M=[1 0;0 3];
[phi,lam]=eig(K,M)
\end{matlab}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

verbatim environments like listings can not be nested in definitions for the simple reason they disable parsing, after `\begin{matlab}` you start verbatim listing mode so `\` does not have its normal meaning so that it can appear verbatim in code listings. so `\end{matlab}` is not the instruction to end an environment it is just the sequence of characters to be typeset.

Obviously the code has to have some way of ending so it looks for the particular string `\end{tcblisting}`.

Many verbatim packages give ways of defining environments that have this behaviour (the way tcblisting is based on lstlisting) but you need to check the package documentation.